# Does the KEPT responsive OpenCart theme work on 2.0?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Can you please confirm whether the [KEPT responsive OpenCart theme](https://themebrowse.net/19982236-kept-responsive-opencart-theme) works on OpenCart 2.0?

Comment: please upload with proper Theme URL. i see it and give quick response to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually KEPT have so many bugs and complaints from the clients.

Kept Theme is working with OpenCart 3.0.2.0 or higher. Your opencart Version is 2.x so this themes is not suitable for you.

You can see other themes for themeforest official website. You can open following URL and see your suitable themes.

https://themeforest.net/search/opencart?platform=OpenCart%202.0.x#content